# How can I add static route in order to access machine that had wrong static IP configured?

Tags: macos, network, router

From time to time I end-up having to connect to a machine that was not configured to use DHCP.

Assuming that I know the static IP address of that machine and that this machine is already physically connected on my network, how do I add a custom route on MacOS in order to be able to ssh to that machine and reconfigure it?

I assume it is something like `sudo route add ...`

Comment: Is the static IP Address that's assigned to the machine in the same subnet as your network?

Answer (score 1):

I do this all the time. There are 2 options:-

`ssh user@<IP>` for a known IP address

or if the machine has a hostname, the Mac should be able to discover it with
`ssh user@hostname.local`

Similar settings can be used from most GUI `ssh` clients.

Answer (score -1):

If the machine is in your network and you know it's IP address, you should be able to connect to it.